# Receiving invitations to submit papers and attend congress's of unrelated fields

Tags: spam, invitations

At the beginning of this year I published my first paper and since then I get multiple emails a day inviting me to attend to congress's, give talks, submit papers etc. in completely unrelated fields (nanotechnology, cancer research, ...). I get addressed as Dr./Prof. very often even though I'm still in doing my Bachelor.

Is this normal, did I tick the wrong box or are these Phishing Attacks? It's getting kind of annoying, I get so many emails!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unfortunately it became normal to receive this kind of academic spam. These journals and conferences are probably predatory journals or conferences which are only interested in the publication fees and do not really provide a reasonable peer-review. My suggestion is to stay away from these.

> I get addressed as Dr./Prof. very often even though I'm still in doing my Bachelor.

This is also quite normal in academia to by default address everybody with one of these titles. In my experience also reputable journal do this.

Comment: Hm okay thank you! I guess Im going to live with it.

Comment: Actually, even without a published paper, if you have a website or such that gives contact information that implies you are in academia, you will attract such predators. Really bad actors might even ignore unsubscribe requests since they confirm that they have reached a live person.